# What power adapter do I need for my Asus R500V K55VD?

Tags: battery, asus-laptop

My brother bought a new laptop so I got his old one (**Asus R500V K55VD**). He didn't include a charger unfortunately so I used an universal charger instead. This isn't satisfactory however so I'm looking for a replacement that has the same specifications as the original one.
The Asus website gives information but I find it very vague. This is a screenshot from their website.

[image: Screenshot from the Asus website]

I have never seen different output for different types of processors before. The sentence as a whole also confuses me. I have a dual core processor so I assume I need a charger with 65W since it uses less power.

How do you interpret this information?

Comment: I do not think you can assume that the dual core uses less power than the quad core - the dual core is *probably* older, and so less efficient. For example, compare the [celeron dual cores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CPU_power_dissipation_figures#Celeron_Dual-Core) with the [i7 laptop cpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CPU_power_dissipation_figures#Intel_Core_i7_2) here, and you'll see that the i7s use anwhere from up to ~50% more power, down to a third that of the celerons. Can you say what the actual processors are in the dual and quad core models?

Comment: Don't mean any disrespect, but why try to figure out all the power ratings when you can do an Internet search by model and get a list of [compatible adapters](https://www.ebay.com/b/ASUS-Laptop-Power-Adapters-Chargers-for-Samsung-N-Series/31510/bn_2784255)?

Comment: @CharlieRB, this is exactly what OP did. In fact his original question provides the screenshot from OEM website that details adapter spec. Its just info provided by OEM is not clear to OP

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sentence is a bit ambiguous if you typed it exactly as shown on manufacturer website. The output of the adapter is the same (universal). The amount of power your laptop will draw from the adapter is different depending on the model. Brief explanation:

**Adapter output:**

- Voltage: 19V DC
- Current: max 4.74A

**Adapter input:**

- Voltage: 100-240V AC (US/EU)
- Frequency 50/60 Hz (EU/US)

**Laptop power consumption:**

- For dual core version: 19V * 3.42A = 65W
- For quad core version: 19V * 4.74A = 90W (this is maximum of the adapter)

**So your buying guidelines should be:**

- Choose adapter with the mains plug suitable for your region (EU / UE / ??)
- Choose adapter which accepts mains voltage of your region ( 50Hz for EU / 60 Hz for US / ??)
- Choose adapter with correct output plug size and polarity (check your laptop socket)
- Choose adapter that has 19V DC output
- Choose adapter that delivers at least 3.42A current (65W), but you can use a more powerful one up to 4.74A with no problem as your laptop will only draw up to its nominal power

Comment: The info you see is a screenshot from the website and I totally agree it's ambiguous. 
I found a webstore that offers replacement parts for my model of laptop and I can choose between 65W and 90W. So you are saying that I can go for the 65W but 90 should also be fine?

Comment: Yes. I am sure that original manufacturer just supplies both models with generic 90W power supply and it works fine for both of them. But if 65W is substantially cheaper and you are sure that your laptop is Dual Core and only needs 65W - go for it.
However from my personal experience it is nice to sometime have (resonably) overpowered PSU. On some (but not all) models that may mean better performance in gaming and faster charging.

Comment: @ArtGertner Your device is not going to run faster with a heavier adapter, what do you base that on?

Comment: Normally not... BUT
I have seen a lot of time when manufacturers design their laptops with tight power calculations for peripherals and there is barely enough power. Then laptop owner connects plenty of devices and the laptop is working on the limit of its adapter's power capabilities. If at the same time GPU or CPU power surge occurs, BIOS will automatically slow the processor down due to not enough power.
This was very common problem with ASUS laptops. A lot of my friends replaced stock adapters with more powerful ones just to be able to use their GPU to the full capacity.

Comment: Ordered a new charger with 90W. It was only an euro more. I can pick up my parcel tomorrow and will let you know how it works

Comment: The new adapter works very well!